# Css grid lines layout

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to create this layout
[image: layout]
I have this aurelia template
[image: aurelia template]
And this CSS rules

```
#containerPlanner {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
 grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

#cabecera {
  display: flex;
  grid-column: 1/4;
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-area: cabecera;
}

#resumen {
 grid-column: 1;
 grid-row: 2;
 border: 2px solid black;
 background-color: aqua;
 grid-area: resumen;
}

#grafica {
 grid-column: 2/4;
 grid-row: 2;
 border: 2px solid black;
 background-color: yellow;
 grid-area: grafica;
}

#opciones {
 display: flex;
 grid-column: 1/4;
 grid-row: 3;
 grid-area: opciones;
}

#datos {
 grid-column: 1/4;
 grid-row: 4;
 grid-area: datos;
}
```

But the result is this

[image: wrong layout]

I don't understand why the resumen section occupies the entire width of the screen if it has grid-column:1.

And the same with grafica section

Any idea please?

Regards

Comment: Notice that in your HTML you have `<div class="containerPlanner">`. But in your CSS you have `#containerPlanner`. None of the grid CSS is applying.

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: Upps sorry. Thanks now work fine